# Doctrine 2 + Zend Form - Populate Dynamic Select Menus

Tags: zend-framework, zend-form, doctrine-orm

I'm building a Zend form that has a dropdown/select menu populated with data from a Doctrine 2 query.

In my repository class, I have the following query in a method named selectUser():

```
$query = $em->createQuery('SELECT u.id, u.name FROM XX\Entity\Users u ORDER BY u.name ASC');
$users = $query->getResult();
```

This returns a multidimensional array, which I'm trying to loop through like this (within the same method):

```
$options = array();
foreach ($users as $key => $value) {
   $options[$value['id']] = $value['name'];
}
return $options;
```

Then in my Zend form class, I try to populate the Select element like this:

```
$id = new Zend_Form_Element_Select('id');
$options = $this->usersRepository->selectUser();
$id->AddMultiOptions($options);
```

The result is an error for each user row that states "Undefined index: [name] in ...UsersRepository.php..." where [name] is the value of the 'name' column in each row.

Does anyone see what I'm doing wrong or how to populate a dynamic select menu using Doctrine 2 and Zend Framework?

(By the way, in order to run the repository method, the form class has protected properties representing the Doctrine container, entity manager, and Users repository. If this isn't considered best practice, I'd welcome any suggestions on improving my technique.)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think your problem is here

$options[$value['id'] = $value['name']];

this would be better

$options[$value['id']] = $value['name'];

Comment: Thanks - gotta love when it's the easy part that's messed up. Will leave this question up as it might help others with Doctrine 2 and Zend select menus.